# php - Log In cannot detect mysqli_num_rows() but logs in anyway

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli, return-value

The code is supposed to echo specific things in its HTML elements if the log in was successful

The problem however is this...Once I get to Log In, it shows a page that says "That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back". when I press the "back" button on the browser, it shows me the HTML elements that were supposed to generate when the log in was successful.

"That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back" was supposed to only show when the query turns out empty or not 1 at least.

Here is the code for reference:

```
<?php
include_once("check_login_status.php");
// Initialize any variables that the page might echo
$e = "";
$joindate = "";
$lastsession = "";

// Make sure the _GET email is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["em"])){
    $e = $_GET["em"];
    // echo $e;
} else {
    header("location: http://www.yoursite.com");
}
// Select the member from the users table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$e' AND active='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
// Now make sure that user exists in the table
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
// echo $numrows;
if( $numrows != 1 ){
    echo "That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back";
    exit(); 
}
// Check to see if the viewer is the account owner
$isOwner = "No";
if($e == $log_email && $user_ok == true){
    $isOwner = "Yes";
}
// Fetch the user row from the query above
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $profile_id = $row["id"];
    $signup = $row["signup"];
    $lastlogin = $row["lastlogin"];

    $joindate = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($signup));
    $lastsession = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($lastlogin));
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $u; ?></title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pageMiddle">
  <h3><?php echo $e; ?></h3>
  <p>Is the viewer the page owner, logged in and verified? <b><?php echo $isOwner; ?></b></p>
  <p>Join Date: <?php echo $joindate; ?></p>
  <p>Last Session: <?php echo $lastsession; ?></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already made a few echo tests and it seems that in this separate test...

```
include_once("db_connect.php");
$e = "MY EMAIL";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$e' AND active='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
// Now make sure that user exists in the table
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
echo $numrows;
```

numrows echos out '1' - whereas in the main code, numrows echoes out ()...which is quite weird since $_GET["em"] is the same as MY EMAIL when I checked via echo.

Comment: `"I have all the code, data and environment, I can use php to run the code and able to see all the error messages, but I cannot debug it. So please debug my code for me using only your eyes and interpreting it on your heads, taking data, environment and error messages as assumption"`.

Comment: can you add some details?

Answer (score -1):

> which is quite weird since ...

No, it's not wired, simply the problem is not there!

I don't see any error so the error is in this PHP:

```
include_once("check_login_status.php");
```

**OR** you are not DB connected

```
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
```

Enable error log in php.ini (see http://php.net/manual/it/errorfunc.configuration.php):

> log_errors = On

and check for error in apache (or what else) web server logs.

**OR** try not to re-invent the "hot water" and use an already done user management class:

[SENTRY @ Cartalyst](http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2)